# Move pdf files to a folder with in the same library

Tags: document-library, file, pdf

In SharePoint doc library I have few files.

When I upload PDF files, these files only should move to a folder called 'PDF' and remaining files will have to move another folder. (These folders are in the same library)

Can anyone please help? How to implement calculated field on this?

Thank you.